# If a fluid element defined by the fluid particle it contains, it becomes useless for turbulent flow, doesn't it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In the book of Batchelor, *Introduction to Fluid Mechanics*, at page 71 the author defines the fluid/material elements as a volume that contains the same fluid particles all the time. In other words, the fluid elements defined by the fluid particles that they contain.

> Nevertheless, the notion of material volumes, surfaces and lines which consist always of the same fluid particles and move with them is indispensable, ...

Assuming an incompressible fluid, the volume of such a volume elements shouldn't change, but this doesn't mean that its shape will not change either. However, due to diffusion and especially in the case of turbulent flow, this implies that fluid particles can easily separate from each other in such a way that after some time t it would be hard to call our fluid volume a *volume*.

If so, isn't this causing any problem in our formulation of fluid mechanics? Or am I totally missing something?